# jQuery Parsing HTML results in Object doesnt support Property error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have to convert table to csv 
I am using following logic to concatenate strings of each td

```
 var $text=(table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.split(", ").join("")).toString();
```

**Assume $ text actually holds the `<font class="Major">testcasedff</font>;`**

When I tried to use Find function for extracting data

```
var data=$text.find('font').text();
```

It actually doesnt work .I am using IE9 as test browser and im getting the following script error

Line: 300
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Please refer to the Fiddle below

Comment: `$text` is s string... You are then trying to use `find` on it

Comment: you need to use `$($text).find(...)`

Comment: $text holds <font class="ClassName">Test Subject1 </font> It is a string

Comment: You are using the wrong character to delimit your code for display in this question... Please refer to my edits :)

Comment: var data=$($text).find('font').text(); It doesnt give any result .

Comment: @AbinayaDevarajan It should. Try recreating your problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

In the following row JQuery convert an HTML Element from string to JQuery Object and so your op will be simplified:

```
var fontObj = $("<font class='Major'>this is a test</font>");
var $textfontObj.text();
```

In pure javascript You will need to create a dummy element, insert yout HTML Element from string and then get the desired result:

```
var targetEleContainer = document.createElement('div');
targetEleContainer.innerHTML = "<font class='Major'>this is a test</font>";
var out2=(targetEleContainer.firstChild).innerHTML;
```

bye

Comment: Sorry @AbinayaDevarajan, it works only if you use JQuery. Instead if you use only javascript without JQuery you are right, it does not work! I supposed you are interested in a simple and rapid way to transform a string to JQuery object and then get the property.

Comment: Hi @AbinayaDevarajan try again your demo: i changed it and added my code: check for "This is " on http://jsfiddle.net/8zrhgy6v/6/  Let me know

Answer (score 0):

textContent dom Property and Parse html works

```
  var $text="<font class='Major'>this is a test</font>";

  var result='';
   var data=$.parseHTML($text);
            $.each(data, function (i, el) {
            result += el.textContent;
            });

 alert(result);
```

Please Checkout the Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Abinaya_WEBGurl/8zrhgy6v/3/